# Cannot compile in Release mode because of CroMagVersion error

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, cromagversion

I have installed CroMagVersion into my solution using NuGet package manager.

It worked just fine in `Debug` configuration. Now that I want to try some `Release` mode I'm struck into this

```
4>  Processing '..\..\packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0\tools\CroMagVersion.tt'... failed.
4>e:\path\to\solution\DataAccessLayers\Org.Zighinetto.MyProject.NHibernate\Org.Zighinetto.MyProject.NHibernate.csproj(161,5): error : (-1,-1): ERROR Error running transform: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unable to find the specified file
4>     in System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
4>     in System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
4>     in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation370e1b87.GetProcessOutput(String localPath, String path, String command)
4>     in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation370e1b87.WriteAttributes()
4>     in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation370e1b87.TransformText()
4>     in Mono.TextTemplating.CompiledTemplate.Process()
4>e:\path\to\solution\DataAccessLayers\Org.Zighinetto.MyProject.NHibernate\Org.Zighinetto.MyProject.NHibernate.csproj(161,5): error MSB3073: exit command "..\..\packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0\tools\TextTransform.exe -o="..\..\packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0\tools\SharedAssemblyInfo.cs" -a="Configuration!Release " -a="SolutionDir!e:\path\to\solution\ " "..\..\packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0\tools\CroMagVersion.tt"" with code -1.
```

Though I have anonymised project names and paths, project structure is kept in the paths.

Basically I have

```
-- Solution dir

  --packages //NuGet's
  --DataAccessLayers
    --Project1
    --Project2
  --FrontEnds
    --Project1
    --Project2
  --ProjectX
  --ProjectY
```

I have triple-checked that:

1. packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0 exists. Check
2. TextTransform exists in the right directory. Check
3. Running `cmd`, `cd`ing into the project directory and issuing `..\..\packages\CroMagVersion.0.3.4.0\tools\TextTransform.exe` doesn't raise a file not found error but correctly invokes program. Check

My solution path **does** contain spaces (solutions are generally placed under `Documents\Visual Studio 20xx` and I'm no exception with 2012)

#### The question is

How do I fix that?

Comment: Forgot to say: the error occurs with all projects

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to CroMagVersion 0.3.5.0 fixed. It was a known bug of the project

```
Release Notes
0.3.5.0 - minor bugfix

    When hg or git was not in PATH, builds could generate spurious exceptions like System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
```

In fact, I don't use git (yet)